# R, igraph: ordered layout

Tags: r, igraph

Let `g` be an `igraph` object. For example, `g <- make_graph(~A-C-B, C-D, E-D-F)`. And let us set up a vertex attribute called `level`

```
V(g)[c("A", "B")]$level <- 1
V(g)[c("C")]$level <- 2
V(g)[c("D")]$level <- 3
V(g)[c("E", "F")]$level <- 4
```

Are there any tools in `igraph` to build a layout for `g` such that it respects `level` in a meaning that a vertex with less `level` is always placed to the left and vertices with same level have the same (or close) abscissa.

So, for the given graph I'd like to see a picture like this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a layout in `igraph` is just a matrix of {x,y} coordinates, you can set the x-coordinates equal to your levels.

```
g <- make_graph(~A-C-B, C-D, E-D-F)
V(g)$level <- c(1,2,1,3,4,4)
l <- matrix(c(V(g)$level,1,2,3,2,3,1),nrow=length(V(g)$level),ncol=2)
plot(g, layout=l)
```

[image]

I just did the y-axis by hand, but you can construct it as you see fit.

---

#### Using Sugiyama layout

Sugiyama layout works by adding layers. There are a lot of options with the layout, but, basically, it tries to create a hierarchical representation of the graph.

```
l <- layout_with_sugiyama(g, layers = -V(g)$level)$layout
#note the "-", this ensures that the smaller level values get small x coordinates

plot(g,layout=l[,c(2,1)])
```

Comment: Passing levels directly to the x-coordinates is a good idea, but I'd also like y's to be set automatically, since I'm going to have lots of graphs from lots of simulations. And it seems to a be a non-trivial task.

Comment: Could try messing around with the Sugiyama layout. It creates layers. Requires some fiddling, but try: `l <-  layout_with_sugiyama(g, layers = -V(g)$level)$layout` (note the "-", this ensures that the smaller level values get small x coordinates). Then: `plot(g,layout=l[,c(2,1)])`.

Comment: Cool! Looks really close to what I want. Could you please update your answer wtih this so that I can accept it?